# TypeError: can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.datetime64

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pytorch

I want to test a particular code, and I wrote the following data loader as an experiment (for a larger project)

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from random import randint
import random

class TestLoader(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, num_profiles):
        self.num_profiles = num_profiles
        self.profiles = {}
        
    def __len__(self):
        return self.num_profiles
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        symbol = random.sample(["A","B","C","D","E"], 1)[0]
        if symbol not in self.profiles.keys():
            country = random.sample(['China', 'UK', 'Germany', 'Fiji', 'Lichtenstein'], 1)[0]
            gender = random.sample(['Male', 'Female', 'Other'], 1)[0]
            self.profiles[symbol] = {"country": country, "gender": gender}

        timeSince = random.uniform(10,80)
        dt=datetime.date(randint(2005,2025), randint(1,12),randint(1,28))
        date = np.datetime64(dt)

        sample = {'value': float(idx), 'country': self.profiles[symbol]["country"], 
                  'gender': self.profiles[symbol]["gender"], 
                  "timeSince": timeSince, "symbol": symbol, "date": date}
        return sample
```

And I have a code like the following to try visualize the code:

```
user_profiles = TestLoader(2000)
batch_size = 40
dataloader = DataLoader(user_profiles, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)


visualize = pd.DataFrame()

for i,data in enumerate(dataloader):
    if i < 10:   
       visualize = pd.concat([visualize, pd.DataFrame(data)], axis = 0).copy()
visualize
```

But then, on the line of `for i,data in enumerate(dataloader):`, I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-584c34ba614b> in <module>
      2 
      3 
----> 4 for i,data in enumerate(dataloader):
      5     pass
      6 #     if i < 10:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py in __next__(self)
    515             if self._sampler_iter is None:
    516                 self._reset()
--> 517             data = self._next_data()
    518             self._num_yielded += 1
    519             if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py in _next_data(self)
    555     def _next_data(self):
    556         index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
--> 557         data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
    558         if self._pin_memory:
    559             data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py in fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
     45         else:
     46             data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]
---> 47         return self.collate_fn(data)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py in default_collate(batch)
     71         return batch
     72     elif isinstance(elem, container_abcs.Mapping):
---> 73         return {key: default_collate([d[key] for d in batch]) for key in elem}
     74     elif isinstance(elem, tuple) and hasattr(elem, '_fields'):  # namedtuple
     75         return elem_type(*(default_collate(samples) for samples in zip(*batch)))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py in <dictcomp>(.0)
     71         return batch
     72     elif isinstance(elem, container_abcs.Mapping):
---> 73         return {key: default_collate([d[key] for d in batch]) for key in elem}
     74     elif isinstance(elem, tuple) and hasattr(elem, '_fields'):  # namedtuple
     75         return elem_type(*(default_collate(samples) for samples in zip(*batch)))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py in default_collate(batch)
     63             return default_collate([torch.as_tensor(b) for b in batch])
     64         elif elem.shape == ():  # scalars
---> 65             return torch.as_tensor(batch)
     66     elif isinstance(elem, float):
     67         return torch.tensor(batch, dtype=torch.float64)

TypeError: can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.datetime64. The only supported types are: float64, float32, float16, complex64, complex128, int64, int32, int16, int8, uint8, and bool.
```

I have some parts later in the code, which really would benefit from using numpy.datetime64, so I prefer to not change the type I am using in the definition of the loader. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have a traceback you can share? That might show the issue occurs - maybe Torch doesn't like `datetime64` for some reason? I don't have specific Torch experience so this is a guess

Comment: @IanOzsvald Thank you for the reminder, I completely forgot to include it. Updated the post now.

Comment: Adding `collate_fn=lambda x:x` in the  `dataloader` is probably worth trying.

Comment: The problem is that `dataloader` tried to convert everything into tensor. But with `lambda` I mentioned above each batch will return a list of 40 `sample` dict. Depending on what you want to do implementing your own `collate_fn` for that will most likely solve the problem.

Comment: I'm not familiar with pandas but if you just want a single `sample` not a batch of them, you can `enumerate(user_profiles)` as well.

Comment: `collate_fn=lambda x:x` worked, thank you!